# Will junction table contain the foreign keys or the primary keys of the individual tables

Tags: database-design, many-to-many, data-modeling

In this link [here](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

they explain how to use junction tables to get around the many-many relationship problem in relational database design.

This line

> If there is no association class, the junction table (sometimes also called a join table or linking table) will contain only the FK attributes from each side of the association.

From the example it seems that the junction table is containing not the **FK** but the primary keys of the individual tables.
`Cust ID, Order Date` together form the composite primary key of orders and UPC is the primary key of `Products`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. Your 'junction' table or 'association' table will the contain the PK values of the tables on either end of the M2M relationship. Often times these are the only two columns in the association/junction table and they can/usually form the PK of the association/junction table.

Comment: To be clear: `{Cust ID, Order Date}` and `UPC` are PKs in the context of their native tables (`Order` & `Product` respectively).  They are FKs in the context of the join table since they refer to PKs in those tables.  (Note that they are *also* a composite PK/UK for the join table itself if there can be at most one `OrderLine` for each {Order, Product} pair).